# OBIEE: Finding frequency in pivot table

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have a pivot table that looks like this:

[image]

My hope is to make the columns of the anomalies (A,B,C,D,M) that is the frequency of the anomaly. So that the column is basically

```
Anomaly/# of Inspections
```

**How can I change the format of these cells to show this frequency so that they can be then plotted over time?**

Comment: Which one.. change the format? Or change the formula?

Comment: @MarkP. ideally change the format so that it displays these frequencies without changing the format. The formula I showed was just to understand my thought process in what I want accomplished

Comment: MySQL? Or Oracle? (Or both?) If it's one but not the other, please EDIT your post and DELETE the unrelated tag.

Comment: @mathguy Oracle but I know OBIEE runs using SQL so I thought MySQL users might be of help because of this. Edited out

Comment: Ok... Confused. You stated "change the format so that it displays these frequencies without changing the format". Change the format without changing the format? Assuming you meant to say change the format without changing the formula, changing the format does not change the values of a column, only the font, or color, or other attributes of a column. You will have to change the formula to recalculate it how you want.

Comment: @MarkP. I want it to say the percentage of anomalies present per number of inspections. I don't want to change data just change how it is presented

Comment: "I want it to say the percentage of anomalies present per number of inspections." You just want a different title? The data that is in those columns is already the percentage of anomalies present per number of inspections?

Comment: @MarkP. No it isn't. It is the sum of errors from all the inspections. I can't change the way the data was given to me but I am trying to change its presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, and a little help from the comments on it, it seems you want to display the volume of anomalies as a percentage of the number of inspections. For example in week 11 you had one Anomaly C, which would be 20% of the 5 inspections.

To display 20% instead of 1, the only way to do this is to change the column formula in the criteria to pretty much what you wrote in your question.

```
100*(Anomaly/# of Inspections)
```

You can't do this through formatting – you can't format a number into different number, you have to change the calculation to do that.

Comment: "You can't format a number into a different number"... this is key! Editing the formula either in the front end application or in the RPD is the way to go if you cant do it in the ETL or underlying database.